# Typescript 'any' type issue for non-existent variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have been working on learning Typescript and have come across an issue I can't seem to resolve. When trying to render a memoized component (I am using React), I get the following error message:

`TS7006: Parameter '_ref' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

The reason this is stumping me, is that for the life of me I can't see where this _ref property is coming from.

Here is the code for both the component, and the page that is trying to render it:

```
// Dependencies
import React, { memo } from 'react';

// Styles

// Props
interface BuildingBlockProps {
  id: number,
  top: number,
  left: number
}

const BuildingBlock: React.FC<BuildingBlockProps> = ({id, top, left}: BuildingBlockProps) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        id={`building-block-${id + 1}`}
        className="absolute w-12 h-12 bg-red-500 rounded-full"
        style={{ top: top + '%', left: left + '%' }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}; 

// Export memoized component
const _BuildingBlock = memo(BuildingBlock);
export default _BuildingBlock;
```

```
import React from 'react';

import _BuildingBlock from '../components/atoms/BuildingBlock';

const TestPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <_BuildingBlock id={1} top={2} left={3}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestPage;
```

I tried checking through my webpack, babel configuration and even things like my Tailwind and postcss config files, but I just can't see what is wrong. If anyone has a suggestion I would greatly appreciate it!

Also, I can provide my package.json dependencies if that would help isolate the potential fix.

Edit:
The full error message I receive is:

```
./src/components/atoms/BuildingBlock.tsx 8:43-47 [tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\liam_\Desktop\Business\Nixon-Digital\Website\nixon-digital\client\src\components\atoms\BuildingBlock.tsx(8,44) TS7006: Parameter '_ref' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14 @ ./src/pages/TestPage.tsx 2:0-63 4:92-106 @ ./src/index.tsx 11:0-40 29:47-55 webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 6817 ms
```

Which so far as I can tell is pointing to the end of the line:
`id: number,`
Which makes no sense to me.

**Update:**
After gutting and rebuilding the project incrementally, I think I have worked out that the culprit is adding the following line to my webpack.config.js file:

`{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "babel-loader" },`

So it seems the problem is to do with using Babel for some reason. I will continue to look for ways to fix this, as I feel Babel is important for transpiling the Typescript.

Comment: What line(s) of code is TypeScript referring to with the error message? Copying that code to [the playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAJQXW), that error is not reported.

Comment: Ah, sorry here is the full error message:

./src/components/atoms/BuildingBlock.tsx 8:43-47
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\liam_\Desktop\Business\Nixon-Digital\Website\nixon-digital\client\src\components\atoms\BuildingBlock.tsx(8,44)
      TS7006: Parameter '_ref' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
 @ ./src/pages/TestPage.tsx 2:0-63 4:92-106
 @ ./src/index.tsx 11:0-40 29:47-55

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 6817 ms

I hope that helps clarify things, but please let me know if you need more!

Comment: What line does `BuildingBlock.tsx(8,44)` refer to? It can't be the 8th line of your first code block, that's just `id: number` in your `BuildingBlockProps` interface.

Comment: (Also, please use the "edit" link to add details to the question, not just comments.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly fresh to StackOverflow, I have edited the error message into the actual post now.

Yeah I tried CTRL-Clicking the location in the error message inside my editor, but it just takes me straight to the end of the `id: number,` line, which I can't fathom why that would be a problem.

Is there any possibility that it could be a mistake in my tsconfig.json file? I could post the setup I have in that file back in my main post, if that would be helpful?

Comment: Maybe some outdated dependencies in package.json?

Comment: Yeah I'm going to strip the project bare until its just React, Webpack and Typescript to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not defining what `memo()` is here:

`const _BuildingBlock = memo(BuildingBlock);`

This should be something like:

`const _BuildingBlock = memo<Props>(BuildingBlock);`

You can inspect the `memo` type definition (right-click in VSCode) to see what type it expects.

Comment: I think the problem may have been because I am using both `ts-loader` and `babel-loader` in the project, as once I removed Babel, it seemed to fix the issue. I am still very new to Typescript and Webpack in general, so figuring out how to transpile properly is still a bit of a thought exercise haha. That being said, I will try reinstalling Babel and babel-loader, but then adding the typing to the props wrapper and seeing if that fixes it. Thank you!